# How to enable outgoing IPv6 traffic on Google Compute Engine VMs?

Tags: networking, ping, ipv6, google-compute-engine

In order to test the accessibility and inaccessibility of my home network from the outside world I'm using Google Cloud Platform VMs with Debian 10. In `ifconfig` I'm seeing one internface with an IPv4 and a link scoped IPv6 address. Afaik the link scoped address doesn't reach outside.

For test purposes I'm attempting an IPv6 connection to google.com. The IPv4 traffic works fine, both `ping` and `curl`, however both `ping -6 google.com` and `ping -6 2a00:1450:4001:82a::200e` (I got the IPv6 address from another machine unrelated to Google) fail due to `connect: Network is unreachable`. `curl [2a00:1450:4001:82a::200e]` fails due to `curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server`.

I'm aware that Google offers IPv6 termination as described [in this stackoverflow.com question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282715/google-cloud-compute-instance-ipv6), however that doesn't enable outgoing traffic afaik.

Maybe it's not possible to achieve what I want since the Google Compute Platform simply doesn't support it, I just want to make sure that I'm not missing a solution.